# How to initialize variable in constructor in PHP

Tags: php, constructor

I am writing this simple code and do not know what the issue with constructor is:

```
class Animal {
    public $_type;
    public $_breed;

    public function __construct ($t, $b) {
        echo "i have initialized<br/>";

        $this ->_type = $t; 
        $this ->_breed = $b;
        echo "type is " .$_type. "<br/>";

        echo "breed is " .$_breed. "<br/>";
    }

    public function __destruct () {
        echo "i am dying";
    }
}

$dog = new Animal("Dog", "Pug");
```

Comment: So What issue you are facing?

Comment: You have to access the variables like this `$this->_type` while doing echo inside constructor.

Comment: use in echo $this ->_breed as while init

Comment: Its a simple question from someone is apparently LEARNING php OOP. Don't downvote it

Comment: @prava how can i get access to $this->_type

Comment: rather then voting it down , the one who wants to vote down , should answer the question and give him solution

Comment: that's true @Arsh and Carlos

Comment: It is actually bad practice echoing directly from a method. Better to RETURN any data either in an array or another object. Imagine what would happen if you now wanted to sub class this class, you have no way of stopping the echo or altering it in any way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this (note the echo lines):

```
class Animal {
    public $_type;
    public $_breed;

    public function __construct ($t, $b) {
        echo "i have initialized<br/>";

        $this->_type = $t; 
        $this->_breed = $b;

        //You have to use '$this' keyword to access
        //class attibutes:
        echo "type is " . $this->_type . "<br/>";
        echo "breed is " . $this->_breed . "<br/>";
    }

    public function __destruct () {
        echo "i am dying";
    }
}
```

Comment: Explain why it does not work and what you did to make it work.

Comment: @SverriM.Olsen, I added my comment first for OP's question. Hopefully, OP can get that. But, anyway thanks for letting me know :)

Comment: Answers should stand alone. You should not have to look around for comments elsewhere to figure out what what is going on. It would take about the same amount of time to add it to the question as it has taken you to reply to me.

Comment: yes it required $this->_breed while declaring, but everytime i will use this variable then again will have to use $this operator again

Comment: Yes, you have to use $this, whenever you want to access those 2 variables as they are now class variables not the normal variables.

Comment: @SverriM.Olsen, (Y) for your concern. Carlos has edited the answer, hope now you like it :).

Comment: okie thank you @prava, is this same happens with functions/methods as well?

Comment: ohh okay .. go ahead and change everywhere then (y)

Answer (score 5):

Why do you have a space after `$this`? Remove the space.
Also, add `$this` when calling a variable.

```
class Animal {
    public $_type;
    public $_breed;

    public function __construct ($t, $b) {
        echo "i have initialized<br/>";

        $this->_type = $t; // <-- remove space
        $this->_breed = $b;  // <-- remove space
        echo "type is " .$this->_type. "<br/>"; // <-- add $this

        echo "breed is " .$this->_breed. "<br/>"; // <-- add $this
    }

    public function __destruct () {
        echo "i am dying";
    }
}
```

Comment: there is no matter if space after $this

Comment: can you explain why Remove the space after `$this` because  some time i also have space in the code after $this but i didn't face any problem

Comment: No it is not still printing the variable value

Comment: yes i agree with parth, space is not the issue, php has leverage about spaces

Answer (score 5):

## You are initializing them fine, but retrieving them wrong...

Since `$_type` and `$_breed` are scoped at the object level, you need to tell PHP what scope you're referencing them in.

Therefore, instead of

```
echo $_breed;
```

You need

```
echo $this->_breed;
```

On a side note, it's very strange practice to prefix variable names with _ these days, even moreso if they are public variables. This will likely confuse other developers working with your code.

Answer (score 4):

With constructor property promotion in `PHP 8`, you can now declare and set properties as parameters of the constructor.

See [here](https://stitcher.io/blog/constructor-promotion-in-php-8).

```
class someClass
{
    // Can delete these declarations and put them in the constructor instead //
    /*
    protected int $id;
    protected string $name;
    protected int $type;
    protected string $frontend_name;
    protected int $account_id;
    protected someOtherClass $object;
    */

    public function __construct(
        protected int $id,
        protected string $name,
        protected int $type,
        protected string $frontend_name,
        protected int $account_id,
        protected someOtherClass $object,) // you can also have a trailing comma now!
    {
        $this->init();
    }
    protected function init() {
        // do other stuff
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Although this not violate the syntax of the php, I suggest that this two lines

```
echo "type is " .$dog->_type. "<br/>";
echo "breed is " .$dog->_breed. "<br/>";
```

must not be put in `__construct()` instead use this outside the class,

Like this,

```
class Animal {
  public $_type;
  public $_breed;

  public function __construct ($t, $b) {
    $this ->_type  = $t;
    $this ->_breed = $b;
  }
  public function __destruct () {
      echo "i am dying";
  }
}

$dog = new Animal("Dog", "Pug");
echo "i have initialized<br/>";
echo "type is " .$dog->_type. "<br/>";
echo "breed is " .$dog->_breed. "<br/>";
```

Answer (score 1):

$_type and $_breed is variable of class so you need to use using `this` keyword

```
 echo "type is " .$this->_type. "<br/>";
    echo "breed is " .$this->_breed. "<br/>";
```