# PHP type hinting with visiblity

Tags: php

What is `protected` inside `protected Service $service` ?

```
public function __construct(protected Service $service)
 {
 }
```

What this feature is called?

If i use protected then i do not need to **declare** and **initialize** the $service. how this is possible?

```
class Sample
{
    public function __construct(protected Service $service)
    {
    }

    public function process()
    {
        $this->service->test();
    }
}

class Service
{

    public function test()
    {
        echo "test";
    }
}

$obj = new Sample(new Service());
$obj->process();
```

Comment: https://wiki.php.net/rfc/constructor_promotion

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37252828/how-to-initialize-variable-in-constructor-in-php, the last answer is what you are seeing here.

Comment: @NigelRen: Because the ordering of the answer can change, it might be better to link to the answer directly: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69821327/724039  (and not to the question)

Answer (score 1):

Its a short hand that introduced in PHP 8 named as [Constructor Property Promotion](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/constructor_promotion)

**Before :**  the definition of simple value objects requires a lot of boilerplate, because all properties need to be repeated at least four times. Consider the following simple class:

```
class Point {
    public float $x;
    public float $y;
    public float $z;
 
    public function __construct(
        float $x = 0.0,
        float $y = 0.0,
        float $z = 0.0,
    ) {
        $this->x = $x;
        $this->y = $y;
        $this->z = $z;
    }
}
```

**After** : But now as PHP introduced [Constructor Property Promotion](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/constructor_promotion) a short hand syntax, which allows combining the definition of properties and the constructor:

```
class Point {
    public function __construct(
        public float $x = 0.0,
        public float $y = 0.0,
        public float $z = 0.0,
    ) {}
}
```